# Need assistance with mathematical logic using BETWEEN with Integers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a mileage entry form:

- Odometer Start
- Odometer End

A simple table that holds:

```
LogID, Start, End
```

I want to prevent the user from entering a start/end pair that clashes with an existing start/end pair. Just having some mathematical brain blockage, could be a real simple solution.

For example:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Log WHERE (@Start + 1) BETWEEN [Start] AND [End]
BEGIN
  -- throw error
END

-- I'll combine these two after I figure out my issue

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Log WHERE (@OdometerEnd -1) BETWEEN [Start] AND [End]
BEGIN
  -- throw error
END
```

This works with the following values, as long as I'm moving forward and the person with the log book enters them in the correct order, such as values like:

```
Start: 50
End: 100

Start: 100
End: 150

Start: 150
End: 200
```

However, if there's a jump, such as:

```
Start: 50
End: 100

Start: 101 <-- here
End: 150

-- I want to allow the following record to be created

Start: 100
End: 101
```

I think I've looked at this too many times. If there's some simple math I'm missing, I'll be glad to feel stupid about it.

EDIT

Here's a somewhat visual representation of what I don't want happening:

```
[----------]
           [-----------]
       [--------] <-- clash
```

My example above stops this, UNLESS it's entered in out of order, which I need to allow:

```
[----------]
           [-----------]
                            [-----------]
                       [----] <-- need to allow
```

Comment: Can you explain your variables? Are you looking to make sure that the odometer start doesn't already exist? Which version of SQL Server are you using? You might be able to use `Lag` to get sensible ranges.

Comment: so basically OK when start == end and next start > start

Comment: or to restate START >= prev end AND END <= next start

Comment: I'll edit my question to give a more visual representation of this. SQL Server 2012

Comment: I hope the edit makes sense. I need to account for every mile, and the mile to mile range may not be entered in order.

Comment: Now that I typed out my own question, I suppose this is really about preventing "overlapping" ranges. That gives me something new to do a search on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing the WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE @end > [Start]
AND @start < [End]
```

Comment: I assume you're not determined to use BETWEEN. ;)

Comment: This doesn't quite work, but may need to adjust some parenthesis. For example, 500 --> 600, and then trying 500 --> 601 allows, but can't have that.

Comment: My New answer covers both of your examples.

Comment: I think this answer is the definitive one.

Comment: Will anyone please upvote my answer or prove it wrong? ;)

Comment: Trying this now... I hope it's as simple as that. This stuff just gets mentally confusing for some reason.

Comment: Yes it does. It's funny that such a visually simple concept can be so confusing when you need to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

So far this is working:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Log WHERE ((@Start + 1) <= [End] AND (@End - 1) >= Start))
    BEGIN
        -- Error out...
    END
```

Can anyone spot a problem? Still hammering away. Why this is so mentally confusing I don't know.

Comment: Can you have the ultimate short trip, e.g. 42 to 42 when you just go to the petrolarium across the street for a fill? That implies something like `13, 42`, `42, 42`, `42, 666` is acceptable.

Comment: No, but good question. At the end of mileage entries they reconcile whatever's left over with not being related to a customer.